# Python + Yandex Direct API: как корректно получить LocationOfPresenceName?

Tags: python, яндекс-директ

У меня есть скрипт на Python, который выгружает данные Яндекс.Директа через API в Google Big Query. Среди прочего выгружаю LocationOfPresenceName либо TargetingLocationName, но в выгрузке получаю значения типа пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ. Как получать значения в нормальной кодировке? Скрипт по ссылке:

[Скрипт](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s7QI0OYvd0LMS91p8SLakJGIfvJyZNXW/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если интересно, я разобрался. Проблема была в функции get_ads_stat. Там есть строка:

data = pd.read_csv(TSV_PATH + name + '.txt', sep='\t', encoding='cp1251')

В ней я указал encoding='cp1251', т.к. промежуточное сохранение в текстовый файл идет именно в ней, а по умолчанию видимо читается как utf8. После этого все значения отображаются корректно.

Comment: Python 3 по умолчанию всё делает в UTF-8, ага